# Converting UTC to Local Time is affected by MS and thus wrong

Tags: java

I have the following UTC time format "**2015-04-22T19:54:11.827Z**"
It was generated using simple Javascript:

```
var d = new Date(); d.toISOString();
```

In Java, I am trying to convert the UTC to Localtime, this is what I get:

```
// MS are 827 -> wrong date (5 minutes difference)!
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.827Z") 
// Wed Apr 22 20:07:47 GMT+02:00 2015

// MS is 0 -> correct date
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'").parse("2015-04-22T19:54:11.0Z") 
// Wed Apr 22 19:54:00 GMT+02:00 2015
```

Ideas?

Comment: Milliseconds are referenced with capital `S`, so try `.SSS` instead of `.sss`.

Comment: As well as the s/S issue, note that because you've quoted the `Z`, it will end up in whatever time zone your code is running in by default, which *isn't* what the value means.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Unless there's a *staggering* coincidence, you appear to be posting basically the same question with two accounts. You should consider asking to have them merged.